# Python in a docker container as alias similar to the gcc compiler

Tags: python, docker

I want to make a virtual compiler environment in docker similar to the gcc one.

```
 alias pip="docker run  -v "$PWD":/root -w /root python:3.6  pip"
 alias python="docker run  -v "$PWD":/root -w /root python:3.6  python"
```

But there is a problem with keeping the changes in the state of the environment made by pip.

I'm expecting to be able to run using the aliases in the following workflow:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python hello.py
```

How to efficiently keep the state after the pip execution so python would be working with the proper libraries installed?

Comment: Have you considered just using a Python `venv`? Ask yourself a question: where does pip install packages?

Comment: if you check `import sys` `print(sys.path)` then you see where python is looking for modules - and there are places where `pip` installs new modules. These places are not in your `/root` so modules are lost when you restart docker. If you want to keep it then maybe you should use `pip install --user` to install modules in user's folder.